# ARC: property vs ivar: copy, weak

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, ivar

From reading [Property vs. ivar in times of ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836182/property-vs-ivar-in-times-of-arc), I understand that ARC will use the `__strong` ownership qualifier when I directly get or set a `strong` property's autosynthesized associated instance variable but will neither call custom getters or setters nor trigger KVO.

But, if I declare a property as `weak` like so:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <XYZExampleViewDelegate> delegate;
```

1. Will the autosynthesized associated instance variable take on the `__weak` ownership qualifier?

   For example, will `_delegate = delegate` (vs `self.delegate = delegate`) in my implementation of

   ```
   - (id)initWithDelegate:(id <XYZExampleViewDelegate>)delegate
   ```

   perform assignment according to the `__weak` qualification?
2. What about for a property declared with `copy`?

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, the property modifier `weak` implies `__weak` ownership. A property's associated instance variable (or backing ivar) is created with the ownership qualifier implied by the property's modifier. See [Clang documentation on ARC property declarations](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations) for a list of property modifiers and which ownership qualifiers they imply.
2. The property modifier `copy` implies `__strong` ownership. So, when setting the backing ivar directly, the new pointee is retained but not copied. To copy it, use the setter.

Comment: For (2), think of it this way: *copy + weak makes no sense*.  The runtime would create a copy of the object, assign it to the `weak` instance variable, then immediately release it because there are no strong references to the copied object...